# Telemetry with gunicorn python application

Tags: gunicorn, open-telemetry, telemetry, tempo

I have a python application that I deploy with docker-compose. All of my microservices are launched using gunicorn.
I want to set up a traces panel in Grafana so I can see what happens inside my application. Besides, I would like not to modify my code applications.

After some research, I found out it was possible using Opentelemetry and Tempo. But the problem is that Opentelemetry is not compatible with gunicorn.
Do you know an alternative to Opentelemetry ? Or an other way to collect telemetry for a gunicorn application ?

Thanks

Comment: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/python/automatic/